# How to set EnableSsl=True while sending emails using ActionMailer.Net?

Tags: model-view-controller, smtp, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailer.Net in my MVC website to send email, I want to send from gmail, but gmail needs EnableSsl=True to be able to send, but I don't know where in ActionMailer.net I can configure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit your web.config file to something like this:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
    <smtp from="some-email@gmail.com">
      <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="some-email@gmail.com" password="valid-password" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Reference:

```
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx\
```